# Qbs: How to enable Qt Quick Compiler?

Tags: qt, qt-quick, qbs

With qmake you can enable Qt Quick Compiler by passing 
`CONFIG += qtquickcompiler`. How can I do this with Qbs?
Or should I write a custom `Rule` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Quick Compiler is not yet supported in Qbs, but will be added eventually.

See [QBS-749](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-749)